# variational principle for the principal eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

I am reading the proof of theorem 2 in chapter 6 Evan PDE.
I have difficulty verifying the following part of the proof, i.e.
[image]

3 questions here.

1) The assumptions $u\in H_0^1(U)$ and $u\in L^2(U)=1$ allow us to write $u=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}d_k w_k$ for $d_k=(u,w_k)_{L^2(U)}.$

2) How to show the series converge in $L^2(U)? $ Well, I know $u=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(u,w_k)w_k$, then $\|u\|_{L^2(U)}=\int_U [\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(u(x),w_k(x))w_k(x)]^2dx$...

3) I have no idea how to show (9).

Appreciate for any helps.

Comment: of course I did. I always have difficulty to do this sort of algebra explicitly...

Comment: you mean, there is no difference between what is given at the bottom 720 and what I asked here?

Comment: I'm saying that if you accept the statements on page 720 as true, then those statements should immediately answer your questions.  On the other hand, maybe your question is actually, "But why are the statements on page 720 true to begin with?"  If that's the case, then your question is really about a general Hilbert space $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of this comes down to understanding definitions.

1. $L^2(U)$ is, by definition, the set of all $u$ of the appropriate domain for which $\|u\|_{L^2(U)}^2 < \infty$.  Since $u$ is an element of $L^2(U)$, the definition of an orthonormal basis tells us that we may write
   $$
   u = \sum_{k=1}^\infty d_k w_k
   $$
   for an appropriate choice of coefficients $d_k$.
2. (2) and (3) come from a property of general Hilbert spaces. In particular: if $H$ is a Hilbert space and the elements $\{w_k\}$ are orthonormal elements, then for any coefficients $d_k$, we have
   $$
   \left\|\sum_{k=1}^\infty d_k w_k\right\|_{H}^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty |d_k|^2
   $$
   which of course means that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |d_k|^2 < \infty$ if and only if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty d_k w_k$ is an element of the Hilbert space.
   To see *why* this is true, it suffices to note that the norm on a Hilbert space comes from an inner product, so that
   $$
   \left\|\sum_{k=1}^\infty d_k w_k\right\|_{H}^2 = 
   \left( 
   \sum_{k=1}^\infty d_k w_k, \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty d_\ell w_\ell
   \right)_H = 
   \sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty d_k \overline{d_\ell} (w_k, w_\ell)_H
   $$
   then, by the definition of an orthonormal basis, we have
   $$
   (w_k, w_\ell)_H = 
   \begin{cases}
   1 & k = \ell\\
   0 & k \neq \ell
   \end{cases}
   $$

Comment: OK. What you wrote makes sense. But how do you show $\sum d_k^2=1$? I mean $\sum d_k^2=\sum_k (u,w_k)_{L^2}^2=u^2 \sum_k w_k^2=\|u\|_2^2.$ And why this equals 1?

Comment: Because they already told you that $\|u\|_{L^2(U)} = 1$

Comment: OK. Then, can you show that, if this 2 assumptions not given, then we cannot express like (8)?

Comment: All we need to express $u$ as in (8) is to have $u \in L^2(U)$.  The assumption that $u \in H^1_0$ has nothing to do with (8) or (9).

Comment: then why assume $u\in H_0^1$?

Comment: Presumably it has to do with another part of the proof.

Comment: You are right, that is all we need to write 8